# How can I run FHIR on Docker?

Tags: docker, hl7-fhir

I generated a FHIRbase, but I'm not sure how to run it on Docker.  I generated it using Synthea.

Right now it's a bunch of JSON data, and I need to make it into a workable database.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on how to deploy the Vonk FHIR server using Docker is here:
http://docs.simplifier.net/vonk/deployment/docker.html#use-docker

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your data looks like, if it is valid FHIR STU3 json you could load it into the [Vonk server](https://simplifier.net/vonk). Vonk is available as a Docker image and is a full RestFul FHIR server.